# How to select Xcode for Qt Creator on mac

Tags: xcode, macos, qt

I've installed Xcode-beta and Qt Creator on mac OS X. Then I install another version of Xcode and run the command

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

But after that the make command on Qt Creator still call `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++`, while the C & C++ compiler of the Qt project is Clang(x86 64bit in `/usr/bin`). How to change clang to one in Xcode instead of Xcode-beta?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I reinstall Qt and solve this problem